# Why did this question about the veracity of a photo get voted down?

Tags: discussion

I posted this question:
[Is this picture of a man in Colorado Springs nearly being blown away, genuine, or a hoax?](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/36730/is-this-picture-of-a-man-in-colorado-springs-nearly-being-blown-away-genuine-o?noredirect=1#comment142129_36730)

I figured it met the guidelines, but I'm wondering why the downvotes. Could I improve this question or is it merely because of the "hoax photo" topic?

Comment: I did not downvote, so I am purely guessing that it was because people thought it was an obvious joke, not a serious claim. I almost edited the title, because "blown away" is ambiguous, and I initially thought it was about an explosion. Perhaps people didn't like that?

Comment: I also did not downvote, but the litter on the floor not being blown away makes this a pretty obvious fake. I think the picture was meant to be humorous, not a convincing forgery.

Answer (score 2):

It's very obviously a joke. Everything about it says "joke". It's a stupid question. Just because a question is legitimate and obeys the rules to the letter doesn't mean it's actually a good question and worth anybody's time.